# Java read data from Excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read data from Excel - only numbers so I can compare it later, I go in a loop and I have code like this:

```
int type = cell.getCellType();
    switch(type){
    case 0:
        int value = (int)cell.getNumericCellValue();
    case 1:
        String temp = cell.getStringCellValue();
        int value = Integer.parseInt(temp);

    }
```

It's like this because sometimes data in Excel have numeric type, sometimes string type.

Now my questions. Is casting to `int` a good idea?
If I have number `1.200` in a cell with type `String` so it's "1.200" how to convert it to `int` (or `float` if it's better)? What is the best way to do it?

All I need is - numbers (sometimes from `String` cell types) so I can compare it with numbers from another datasource.

Comment: Please also use the constants from Cell for "case 0" and "case 1", e.g. Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC and Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3):

`CellType.Numeric` refers to cells whose contents contain **integers**, **fractions** or **dates**.

Therefore, if you are reading cells that can potentially have more than one specific numeric type then you will need to put in further work to narrow the classification.

`getNumericCellValue()` returns a `double` (assuming the cell is of type `CellType.Numeric`)

Casting this `double` to `int` will result in the decimal and all digits after being dropped. So `1.200` would become `1`. Hence it is likely in your case that casting it as a `float` is better. If you want to ensure no loss in accuracy then don't cast at all; just save it as a `double`.